# Entity framework update entity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUserProfile(UserProfiles _postedUserProfile)
{
    UserProfiles orjinalUserProfile = entity.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserId == _postedUserProfile.UserId).Single();
    orjinalUserProfile.AboutMe = _postedUserProfile.AboutMe;
    orjinalUserProfile.Birthday = _postedUserProfile.Birthday;
    orjinalUserProfile.Comments = _postedUserProfile.Comments;
    ...... // there are lines more 
    entity.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

I updated entity like above. But I think this way is not good. Is There any solutoin to update entity in a line, for example insert operation like `entity.AddToUserProfiles` .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ApplyCurrentValues method.

Here is an example: [ApplyCurrentValues in EF 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272325/applycurrentvalues-in-ef-4)

Basically:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUserProfile(UserProfiles _postedUserProfile)
{
    UserProfiles orjinalUserProfile = entity.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserId == _postedUserProfile.UserId).Single();
    entity.UserProfiles.ApplyCurrentValues(_postedUserProfile);
    entity.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I try this. But there is no change on database. I cant understand How do orjinal and modified entity matches between them in above code?

Comment: i noticed a mistake with my original post.  I was passing orjinalUserProfile to the ApplyCurrentValues method, instead of _postedUserProfile. I've edited to reflect the change. Try using this object instead.

Comment: It still does not work. Should we ensure relationship between orjinal and posted entity?

Comment: Yes, i assumed they had the same primary key value.