# Why do I need to get an old entity before calling ApplyCurrentValues on another object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

It looks like this snippet of code doesn't work unless I include the first line of the snippet which is **not** referenced anywhere afterwards? Is this how `ApplyCurrentValues` method works?

```
_entities.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == contactToEdit.Id);
_entities.Contacts.ApplyCurrentValues(contactToEdit);
_entities.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

This code edits a contact record and saves to the database.

Here's the entire method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Contact contactToEdit)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }

    try
    {
        _entities.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == contactToEdit.Id);
        _entities.Contacts.ApplyCurrentValues(contactToEdit);
        _entities.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, the object context needs to know somehow which fields have changed.
The fields will appear updated to it only **if the context kept record of the original values**.

The first line seems to have a side-effect of making the object context *aware* of the original values (through loading the entity).

Take a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272325/applycurrentvalues-in-ef-4/2273493#2273493) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264313/entity-framwork-4-not-always-updating-boolean-property-using-applycurrentvalues/2278322#2278322) answers.